# Is there a CallByName equivalent for global functions?

Tags: vb6

I want to do this: "If there's a module *X* containing a function *Y* then call it, otherwise don't."

I'm aware that I can use `CallByName(Object, MethodName, ...)`  to call a method or property of an object instance.

Is it possible to call a global sub/function which is not bound to an object?

```
//Module1
Public Sub DoSomething
End Sub

//Module2
Public Sub TriggerDoSomething
  On Error Resume Next
  CallByName2 "Module1", "DoSomething", ...
End Sub
```

I know, it would be better to refactor my code to wrap `DoSomething` into a class, but currently this is not possible as it would break the code of my coworkers in a way that could not be fixed in a few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really would be easier to CallByName a class - can't you just wrap the module(s) with a class that redirects the calls to the module?

It's possible to call routines in modules by name using a FunctionDelegator. This is explained in Matt Curland's excellent book [Advanced Visual Basic 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201707128).

Googling might find you some hacks using CallWindowProc, but Matt Curland says that's dangerous. Which is pretty much the final word on the matter :)

---

EDIT: RS Conley's answer doesn't use a module, use a class that has a instancing property of GlobalMultiUse and you will be able to use CallByName. This will work if your code is in a DLL rather than an EXE. RS Conley suggests in any case it is more flexible to have a minimal EXE with nearly all functionality in a DLL: this may well be true.

Answer (score 1):

Could conditionnal compilation be ok for your problem ?

```
//Module2
Public Sub TriggerDoSomething
    #If DoSomething_IsPresent Then
        DoSomething
    #End if
End Sub
```

Then in your project settings you would add the following conditionnal compilation arguments :

- If DoSomething is present : DoSomething_IsPresent = -1
- If DoSomething is not present : DoSomething_IsPresent = 0

---

By the way, be careful with the "On Error Resume Next" in :

```
//Module2
Public Sub TriggerDoSomething
  On Error Resume Next
  CallByName2 "Module1", "DoSomething", ...
End Sub
```

If DoSomething is present in Module1 but has an unhandled error you won't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a module, use a class that has a instancing property of GlobalMultiUse and you will be able to use CallbyName

Comment: Nice idea. Won't that require the class to be moved to a DLL project? Which you could do & it wouldn't break client code of the module. I couldn't make it work in an EXE. (Had to change to ActiveX exe to even set class to GlobalMultiUse.)

Comment: Correct if the class resides in a EXE. I rarely do that anymore preferring to have a minimum of a EXE linked to a DLL. It just more flexible that way.

Comment: You might be right. Maybe you should edit the answer to explain that? It's possible DR doesn't already have the code in a DLL. BTW If you have no objection I'm going to edit my answer to include your idea. Leave a comment on it if you'd like me to take it out. I've +1 on your answer.

Comment: No problem the points of all this is to get the right answer out.

Comment: Great! BTW I browsed some of your other answers. I like the sound of the structure of your VB6 app, I wish our legacy apps were as neat as that. Unfortunately we change them fairly infrequently so they only improve very slowly

Comment: Thanks. It was a problem for us as well. What we did is first develop the model the core libraries. Then put anything that modified the model into a Command Object. The forms now created and execute command objects. Then we added the UI interfaces. At each point we had working software.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it folks.
I accept donations.

```
Public Sub callbyname2(proc As String)
    Dim vbComp As VBComponent
     For Each vbComp In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Run (vbComp.name & "." & proc)
        If Err.Number <> 1004 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 'ActiveWorkbook' is part of the Excel object model if I recall correctly so isn't this VBA code rather than VB6 code?

Comment: absolutely. but if you dont have to use excel/office, you really should not use VB I guess