# VB6 CallByName woes

Tags: vb6, callbyname

I want to do a CallByName for some Subs but I just can't get it to go.

Everything goes fine until execution reaches the `CallByName`, then I have problems:

- Whenever I use `Me`, it complains about a  compile error
- And if I use `frmMyServer`, it says "object or method not supported"

**Question: How do I do this?**

This is what I have :

in my 'modHandleData'

```
Private Sub HandleRequestScriptedNPC(...)
    ' ...
    NPCMethod = "Scripted_Npc_" & NpcNum
    CallByName Me, NPCMethod, VbMethod, NpcNum, Index
End Sub
```

in my 'modScriptedNPC'

```
Public Sub Scripted_Npc_9(ByVal NpcNum As Long, PlayerNum As Long)
    SendOneOptionMsg PlayerNum, "NPC 9", "NPC 9 talks." & vbCrLf & "Then gives you a clue"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re calling the code in a *module*, so there is no `Me` instance (that only exists in classes, including forms). My VB6 is a bit rusty, but I believe you **cannot** call methods in modules using `CallByName` since you need an object.

Comment: +1 Quite true, you can't call methods in modules using `CallByName`. If you are prepared to get very hardcore there are other ways to do it, but I don't recommend them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609894/is-there-a-callbyname-equivalent-for-global-functions/609926#609926