# Function to absorb an error in VB6?

Tags: vb6, error-handling

Sometimes there's a function that will throw an error in certain situations, and you'd like to use that function, but in your particular use case, the situation that causes the throw is not really an error situation.  For example, maybe there's a function to remove an entry from a key-value set, which throws an error if there is no such key in the collection, and returns the deleted value if there was.  And that's great in a lot of cases, but in some specific case you want to remove an entry *if it is there*, and you don't care if it's not there.

So either you litter you code with multiple "On Error" lines:

```
' General error handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' Do some stuff
(...)

' Don't throw an error just because the key doesn't have an entry
On Error Resume Next

' Delete it if it's there
DeletedValue = Delete(Key)

' Go back to regular error handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' Do some more stuff
(...)
```

Or else you write a little wrapper function:

```
Public Function DeleteButDoNotThrowError(ByVal Key As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    DeleteButDoNotThrowError = Delete(Key)

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    DeleteButDoNotThrowError = vbNullString
End Function
```

I hate the first way - it seems so verbosely polluted to me - so I normally use the second way.  But what I'd really like is to not have to write such wrappers over and over every time I want to use a function in that way.  So I'd like something like:

```
Public Function AbsorbErrorString(ByVal CallReturn As String, _
        ByVal ErrorReturn As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    AbsorbErrorString = CallReturn

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    AbsorbErrorString = ErrorReturn
End Function
```

Which you would then (in my fantasy world) be able to use like this:

```
DeletedValue = AbsorbErrorString(Delete(Key), vbNullString)
```

But of course that doesn't work, since it's not the case that AbsorbErrorString is calling Delete; rather, the main function is calling Delete, and if that succeeds, then and only then does the main function call AbsorbErrorString.  So the error thrown by Delete causes AbsorbErrorString to be bypassed entirely, and therefore not caught by AbsorbErrorString's error handler.

Is there a way to do something like I want, in a relatively clean and not-too-verbose way?

Comment: You may want to look into the [CallByName method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629847/1316573). I think you should be able to use it to achieve your fantasy state.

Comment: Daniel Cook, thanks, but that would only work if the desired underlying function is a member of an object, right?

Comment: That's correct. Here is [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/609894/1316573) that talks about possible alternatives.

Comment: How many functions fall into this category?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not possible except by passing the code to execute as a string (as Daniel Cook mentioned).

All I can suggest is a minor tweak to your second example simpler in order to reduce boilerplate code. It's not much, but it's about as good as can be done in VB6.

```
Public Function SafeDelete(ByRef Key As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    SafeDelete = Delete(Key)
ErrorHandler:
End Function
```

If `Delete` raises an error, SafeDelete will still have it's old value, which defaults to the empty string. It's then OK to fall through the (now-empty) error handler. Also, you'll want to use ByRef rather than ByVal for performance, in case the wrapped function wants it ByRef. (It also saves an unnecessary string copy, according to some of my coworkers.)